# GPIO Pin configurations

Tags: microcontroller, gpio, pullup, pulldown

I went through the data sheet of STM32F4 and found the pin configuration of GPIOs. I don't understand the difference between these configurations:

- Input floating
- Input pull-up
- Input-pull-down
- Analog
- Output open-drain with pull-up or pull-down capability
- Output push-pull with pull-up or pull-down capability

I have used some of these configurations by vaguely understanding it. Could you help me to understand how this works? What is the difference between these configurations?

Answer (score 2):

**Input floating**: Input Floating means Pin can be used as a input and it is not "tied" to anything (means neither pull up nor pull Down) hence called as floating.

**Input pull-up**: Input pin which is internally pulled up with a resistor (Pin connected with VCC Via a resistor). Resister value can be found in the datasheet.

**Input-pull-down**: Input pin which is internally pulled down with a resistor (Pin connected with GND Via a resistor). Resister value can be found in the datasheet.

**Analog**: Analog pin might be connected with an internal DAC or ADC. and can be used for analog application like voltage sensing or controlling the brightness of an LCD.

**Output open-drain with pull-up or pull-down capability**: Open Drain output can be treated as transistor's collector, to get high state requires a pullup resistor.

**Output push-pull with pull-up or pull-down capability**: push-pull structure generally refers to two transistors (One PNP and other NPN) are controlled by two complementary signals.Either of the transistor gets on while the other turns off.